# fnGetData() is not recognized

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is a `dataTable` :

```
<table id="list_details_livraison" class="striped cell-hovered border bordered" data-searching="true">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.article');?></th>
             <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.qtelivrer');?></th>
             <th style="text-align: center;"></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
</table>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     var dt = $('#list_details_livraison').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "oLanguage": {
                // switch lang here with a PHP variable 
                "sUrl": "<?php  echo RP_LANG ?>fr_FR.txt",
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: "<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_details_livraisons.php?livc_code=<?php echo $data[0]['livc_code']; ?>",  
            "aoColumnDefs": 
                [
                {
                    "aTargets": [1],
                    "mData": 1,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<div style="text-align:center;">'+ data +'</div>';
                     }
                },
                {
                    "aTargets": [2],
                    "mData": 2,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                if (isDetailLivraisonValider(data)) {
                                    return '<div style="text-align:center;">'+
                                            '<span class="mif-checkmark mif-2x fg-lightGreen"></span>'+
                                          '</div>';
                                } else {
                                    var article = '\''+full [1]+'\'';
                                    return '<div style="text-align:center;">'+
                                            '<a href="../../RestaurantLivraison/modifierDetail/'+ data +'" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="mif-pencil mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                            '<a href="#" id="staticDialog" onclick="afficheDlg(\''+ data +'\','+article+')" style="color:red;"><span class="mif-cross mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                          '</div>';
                                }
                     }
                }],
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25,50,100, -1], [10, 25,50,100, "Tout"]]
        });
        var nb = dt.fnGetData().length;
        alert("number of rows = "+nb);
});
</script>
```

At runtime there is no alert showing and console said "TypeError: dt.fnGetData is not a function" !

If I replace DataTable by dataTable then I got 0 as returned result though there are 2 rows shown ! The version of dataTable I am using is 1.10.6

So what is wrong ?

Comment: I think you need to read this: https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10 (specifically the part about `fn` functions being deprecated in favour of their newer api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log(dt.fnGetData($('#list_details_livraison')));
```

also try to change:

```
var dt = $('#list_details_livraison').DataTable({
```

to:

```
var dt = $('#list_details_livraison').dataTable({
```

Answer (score 0):

1.10.6 fnGetData() is changed to data() function.  You can find convert info [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

```
var lengthData= dt
    .rows()
    .data().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

When datatables moved to version 1.10+, the hungarian notation changed to camel case notation
In your case, fngetdata changed to row().data()
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()

Here is the full list of upgrade notes for 1.9 to 1.10

https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because I was configuring a column at an index that didn't existed.
Example:

```
const DTable = table.DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [0]
        },
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [2],
            className: 'editable'
        },
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [6], // <--- Wrong index, my table only had 5 columns
            className: "no-select"
        }
    ],
})
```

Setting the target to `targets: [4]` solved this error for me.